# Error in Exponential Sum Formula

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, exponential-function, mathematical-physics, education

I have noticed that, for the exponential sum formula:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} r^n = \frac{1-r^N}{1-r}.$$
the formula is not correct (left side $\neq$ right side) when N has a factional part (not just integer).
Could you please help me to understand why?
Here is an example in Matlab

```
clc
clear all
r = 0.5;
N=2.4;
%% left side of equation
left = 0;
for n=0:N-1
    left = left + r^n;
end
%% right side of equaiton
right = (1-r^N)/(1-r);
right-left
```

Comment: What does $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} r^n$ mean if $N$ is not an integer?

Comment: With Matlab, in the loop control instruction "for n=0:N-1" you take a non-integer $N$ for example $N=2.4$: the loop will stop not at $n=1.4$ but at the largest integer less or equal to $1.4$, i.e., it integer part indeed $n=1$. No surprize that there is a discrepancy with the RHS...

Comment: @JeanMarie yes I totally agree with you, I posted this question to see how people usually deal with this formula when N is not an integer... Thanks

Comment: @MartinR, Hi Martin, I am doing some research in electronic engineering and it happened that N is a non-integer

Comment: @AmroGoneim: Sum in mathematics is defined for discrete sets, so question of Martin R is highly reasonable. What do you mean by this sum for non-integer $N$? For example, what you expect right hand side to be for $N=2.4$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the fact that $N$ is not an integer. It makes no real sense here since your summation indices cannot be fractional (and thus the upper bound cannot be either).

Your summation will stop at index $N=2.4$ rounded down, so as suggested in the comments, there will be a discrepancy which yields a wrong result. Working with integer values for $N$ will solve the problem.